# How do I check if a compiler error shows in cmd?

Tags: c++, cmd, compiler-errors

I decided to make it easier for me to compile and run my C++ programs through command prompt (I use `cmd` in conjunction with Sublime Text).

I added a `cmd` command (dragged .bat file in system32) to jump to my C++ files directory, and then a few more commands to compile my three work files.

I wanted `cmd` to output "Compiling work.cpp..." (which I've implemented) and *if it doesn't return an error*, output "Successfully Compiled" (What I don't know how to do). Is there anyway to implement this in `cmd`? 
I'm using `g++ (tdm64-1) 5.1.0`

Comment: Sounds like a job for `make`.

Comment: You should check the error code returned by compiler, if `%errorlevel%` is 0 then it succeeded.

Comment: `if errorlevel 1 echo An error occurred! & pause` or `if not errorlevel 1 echo Compiled successfully.`. Please read the Microsoft support article [Testing for a Specific Error Level in Batch Files](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/69576) for details on how to evaluate the exit code of a called application like the compiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `errorlevel` "environment variable":

```
g++ work.cpp
if %errorlevel% == 0 echo "Successfully Compiled"
```

This uses the syntax of environment variables (the `%` part), but `errorlevel` is a special "variable", which holds the status of recently finished command. If the status is 0, it was successful, otherwise an error occurred.